# Mixing SQL inner and outer joins

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join

I have the following legacy Oracle SQL query that I am working with:

```
SELECT *
FROM
table1, table2, table3, table4
WHERE 
    table1.job= table2.job(+)
AND table1.event = table3.event(+)
AND
    ((table2.column1= table4.key AND table4.resource_type = 'xxx')
    OR (table2.column2 = table4.key AND table4.resource_type = 'yyy'))
```

I see that table has a left outer join on table2 and table 1 has a left outer join on table3. But now what does the last clause do?

When I look at the Venn diagram, I think it's returning all of table1 plus the records that table2 and table4 have in common. So is this query performing a kind of union of the two datasets?

Comment: If you were using the modern explicit `JOIN` syntax instead of the ancient, outdated implicit joins in the where clause things would be a lot easier to understand (and besides: even Oracle recommends to not use the proprietary `(+)` any more)

Comment: Please edit your question and include the query plan generated for the above query. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `LEFT JOIN` to `table2` is really an `INNER JOIN`.  The `WHERE` clause is undoing the outer join.  So I think this is the equivalent query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 JOIN
     table2
     ON table1.job = table2.job JOIN
     table4
     ON (table2.column1 = table4.key AND table4.resource_type = 'xxx') OR
        (table2.column2 = table4.key AND table4.resource_type = 'yyy') LEFT JOIN
     table3
     ON table1.event = table3.event;
```

[Just to be clear](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries006.htm) on the point about turning the outer join to an inner join:

> If the WHERE clause contains a condition that compares a column from
>   table B with a constant, then the (+) operator must be applied to the
>   column so that Oracle returns the rows from table A for which it has
>   generated nulls for this column. Otherwise Oracle returns only the
>   results of a simple join.

Comment: But table2 isn't compared to a constant, it's compared to a column in another table.

Comment: @codecypher . . . So?  There is no `(+)`, so it requires that the columns have a non-NULL value.  Hence, that undoes the outer join.

Answer (score 0):

Table 4 has records of (at least) two resource types { 'xxx', 'yyy' }. Table 2 has the corresponding IDs for resource type 'xxx' in column 1 and for resource type 'yyy' in column 2.

Answer (score 0):

The last clause, i.e. `((table2.column1= table4.key AND table4.resource_type = 'xxx') OR (table2.column2 = table4.key AND table4.resource_type = 'yyy'))` actually turns the "left join" on `table2` into a join, more specifically into something like `table1 join table2 join table4`, such that the query will *not* necessarily contain all records of `table1`.

You can think of that as follows: Suppose `table1` and `table2` are actually left joined, such that the (intermediate) result contains all tuples from `table1` combined with the attributes of `table2` where `table1.job` and `table2.job` match, and with null values for the `table2`-attributes where `job` does not match. Then, a `where`-condition like `table2.column1= table4.key` will remove all records from the (intermediate) result where `table2.column1` does not match any record in `table4`; note thereby that a `null`-value in `table2.column1` yielded by the left join will never match and will let these records being filtered out. Hence, you won't have any records in the result where `table1.job` and `table2.job` do not match.